# How Do I use Excel Data to Color Shapes in Visio? - Microsoft Visio 2010

Tags: excel, visio

I'm trying to create a live display using data that is coming from my excel sheet.
How can I fill a shape based on cell data  i. e. 0=red and 1=green?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visio 2010 Professional or Premium, you can use Data Graphics / Color By Value
If you only have the Standard edition, then you can use the Database Wizard to map values in an Excel column to FillForegnd

Alternatively, you can customize your Master shape to set the FillForegnd cell value when the value of value in another cell changes.
Visio does have a default Color Map, with sensible colors from 0 to 13, and shades of gray between 14 and 24.

[image: Default Visio Color Map Numbers]

However, you probably want to specify the RGB values instead.

So, if you have a Shape Data row called Prop.MyDataRow, which has values say between 0 and 5, then you could do the following.

Set the formula of FillPattern to =GUARD(1) - this prevents anyone accidently overwriting the formula, and thus blasting your hard work. The shape will have Solid fill.

Set the formula in FillForegnd to =GUARD(INDEX(Prop.MyDataRow,"0;1;2;3;4"))
Or
Set the formula in FillForegnd to =GUARD(INDEX(Prop.MyDataRow,"RGB(0,0,0);RGB(255,255,255);RGB(255,0,0);RGB(0,255,0);RGB(0,0,255)"))

This formula works for English. The separator character could be different in other languages.

To overcome this, you could use the alternative formula
=GUARD(INDEX(Prop.MyDataRow,RGB(0,0,0)&"~"&RGB(255,255,255)&"~"&RGB(255,0,0)&"~"&RGB(0,255,0)&"~"&RGB(0,0,255),"~"))
Visio will automatically use the RGB separator in your language.

As you can see, there are many ways of achieving the automatic color changing.